# Watch and download youtube video simultanously

Tags: downloading, youtube, cache

So I can watch a youtube video, great. But once I go out of range of wifi I can't play it.

So the other option, is, I use a program to download the video. But I can't play it before it's downloaded.

So is there like a program that you see the video, but after it has been downloaded, it's not discarded but permanently saved ?

Comment: Probably below [tubemate or easytube] apps really very helpful and it will give exactly what you want. There is an another way too, if you are using firefox app, you can try "save from.net helper" add-ons, that can download your video while watching video.

Answer (score 4):

There are apps like [TubeMate](http://m2.tubemate.net/) or [EasyTube](http://easytube.me/) that let you download Youtube videos to your phone internal storage or to the SD card in order to allow you to see these videos whenever you want wherever you want.

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could always:

Set it up downloading using 'TubeMate': http://www.androidfreeware.net/download-youtube-tubemate.html

Then watch it on the normal YouTube app!

If you go out of range, hope that the download has finished and you can carry on watching it offline!